# CarbonクラスをPHP UNIT TEST時にMockeryを使ってモッキングできない

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mock

現在Laravelでの開発でPHP UNITテストを行っております。

ServiceクラスのメソッドでCarbonクラスをインスタンス化して、RepositoryクラスのメソッドにCarbonインスタンスオブジェクトを渡している処理があるのですが、その処理で渡しているCarbonクラスの値をMockeryを使ってモッキングしようとしているのですが、エラーが出てうまくモッキングできません。

CarbonクラスはDIしたほうがいいのでしょうか？

```
class HogeServiceImp implements HogeServiceInterface
{
    private $fugaRepository;

    public function __constract(FugaRepository $fugaRepository)
    {
        $this->fugaRepository= $fugaRepository;
    }

    public function hogeMethod()
    {
        $now = new Carbon::now();
        $this->fugaRepositroy->fugaMethod($now);
    }
}
```

```
public function test_hogeMethod動作確認()
{
    $dateTime = Carbon::now();
    $carbonMock = Mockery::mock('overload:' . Carbon::class);
    $carbonMock->shouldReceive('now')->andReturn($dateTime);

    $repositoryMock = Mockery::mock(FugaRepository::class);
    $repositoryMock->shouldReceive('fugaMethod')-with($dateTime);

    app()->instance(FugaRepository::class, $repositoryMock);
    $hogeService = app()->make(HogeService::class);
    $hogeService->hogeMethod();
}
```

Comment: 1. 「エラーが出て」というエラーを一度掲載したほうが良いかもしれません。
2. HogeServiceImp でnew Carbon::now();としていますが、Carbon::nowはコンストラクタではないのでnowは不要な気がします。

Answer (score 2):

HogeServiceImp の方での Carbon の使い方は問題ないです．
Carbon は，インスタンスを new していくつも作ることが当たり前のものですし，インスタンスそれぞれが固有の値（日付の情報）を持つような性質のクラスなので， コンストラクタやセッターから DI するようなものではありません．どちらかというと「依存するクラス」というより「（感覚としてスカラーに近い）値」と考えると分かりやすいかもしれません．

一方で，基本的にモックしたいようなものは DI し，ふつうにモックを注入できるようにした方が良いです．したがってオートロード時に無理やり行う overload モックはできるだけ使わず，これは最終手段だと思ってください．

ここまでを踏まえ，今回どのように対処できるかというと， `Carbon::setTestNow()` をテストクラス側で使用し，Carbon が now() で返す時間をテスト側からコントロールすると良いと思います．

```php
public function test_hogeMethod動作確認()
{
    // Carbon::now() は，これ以降 2023-01-01 00:00:00 を返すようになります
    Carbon::setTestNow('2023-01-01 00:00:00');

    $repositoryMock = Mockery::mock(FugaRepository::class);
    $repositoryMock
        ->shouldReceive('fugaMethod')
        -with(equalTo(Carbon::parse('2023-01-01 00:00:00')));

    app()->instance(FugaRepository::class, $repositoryMock);
    $hogeService = app()->make(HogeService::class);
    $hogeService->hogeMethod();
}
```

上記のように `Carbon::setTestNow('2023-01-01 00:00:00')` で時計を固定してあげることで， `HogeServiceImp::hogeMethod()` 内での `Carbon::now()` は 2023-01-01 00:00:00 な状態を持つ Carbon インスタンスを返すようになります．

また，ここで使っている `equalTo()` は，オブジェクトを曖昧比較（＝＝＝ ではなく ＝＝）するためのマッチャーです．
これを使うことで， FugaRepository::fugaMethod() が引数に Carbon::parse('2023-01-01 00:00:00') を受け取ることを期待できます．
参考： https://readouble.com/mockery/1.0/ja/argument_validation.html